# Do I have to enter "npm init" before installing packages using npm or can i use it afterwards as well?

Tags: node.js, npm

I know that I can run the node.js app just as well without using `npm init` and moving straight to installation but as a good practice, if I forget to run `npm init` initially, what can I do improve my application?

Initially, I used the `npm install <package name>` instead of `npm init` and now I want to know that although my app will still run, it there any way I can improve my application if I forget to use `npm init` again?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install <package name>` & `npm init` are not the same commmands.

`npm install <package name>` is used to download a package that's in the NPM repository while `npm init` is used to initialize a project and creates a `package.json` file. This file keeps track of libraries installed in the project by adding the installed package's name and version.

If you did not initialize the project and proceeded to run `npm install <package_name>`, npm will install the package, create the `package.json` file and add the recently-added package to it.